# Is there any case-callbacks for robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm writing lib for robot framework on python. My lib has scope `'TEST SUITE'` because I need it to use one initialization and one finalization for suite. But also I need it to make some actions after every test case. For now I defined one keyword and manually added it to "test teardown" but I want to catch this event automatically. Can I use any callback in Robot framework or anything else for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom library method trigger before and after a test case is run, then that can be achieved using a [Robot Framework Listener Interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface).

In the [Python example](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-examples) you see how each of the supported methods is processed.